# How to run a python program more than once

Tags: python

How do I make my python program run more than once without having to restart it.
Below is the code:

```
words = [str(x) for x in raw_input().split(' ')]

string = raw_input()

def word_search():

    for x in words:

        while len(string)==30:
            if x in string:
                print x, 'appeared', string.count(x), 'time(s)'
            else:
                print x, 'appeared', string.count(x), 'time(s)'

            break

        else:
            print 'Your longer string should not be less or more than 30.'
word_search()
```

Comment: `for i in range(n): word_search()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop. Also, 'string' is not a good variable name.

```
def word_search():
    words = [str(x) for x in raw_input().split(' ')]
    string = raw_input()
    for x in words:

        while len(string)==30:
            if x in string:
                print x, 'appeared', string.count(x), 'time(s)'
            else:
                print x, 'appeared', string.count(x), 'time(s)'

            break

        else:
            print 'Your longer string should not be less or more than 30.'
While True:    
    word_search()
```

You can use `break` in the main loop to exit

Comment: I have used it before and it didn't work. I need the program to start over again and accept new inputs.

Comment: The code I provided will do that. Your problem is that you are asking for input outside of the loop, I fixed that in lines 2 and 3